# register mouseout handler on disabled html-element (IE8)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, mouseout

I have a problem with my tooltip library in IE8. For some elements, especially elements with the '*disabled*' property set, the mouseout-handler (hiding a tooltip by setting it's display property to 'none') just doesn't get registered, so the tooltip stays visible when the mouse leaves the element (mouseover does work). The handler is registered using the `attachEvent` method. The problem doesn't occur in other browsers and not in IE up to version 7, so I suppose it's a specific IE8 problem (bug?). Anyone encountered this problem? Anyone solved it?

Comment: It would help if you can post the code.

Comment: I would have if I didn't find the solution already ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: the *disabled* property is not allowed for other than input elements, so just removing the property restored the desired functionality in IE8. I suppose IE8 handles things more strict.